# React router dom 6 and bootstrap 2.5 nav link renders entire app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

When I click on a Nav.link in my SPA application the entire page re-renderss, but I only want the content in the main portion of the UI to change based on the link being clicked. In the layout I have a header nav and then one row and two columns. The content of the header nav never changes, and the left column is a static list of clickable Nav links. The only content I want to change is the content of the right column based on the link that is clicked, and I do not want to re-render the entire app, just the content of the column.

App.js

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <CommonComponent/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

CommonComponent

```
    <>
      <Navbar>
        <div></div>
      </Navbar>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
            <Nav.Item href="/a">
              <Nav.Link href="a">Comp A</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="b">Comp B</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="c">Comp C</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="d">Comp D</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={8} sm={8} md={8} lg={9} xl={10}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="a" replace />} />
              <Route path="/a" element={<CompA {...props} />} />
              <Route path="/b" element={<CompB {...props} />} />
              <Route path="/c" element={<Compc {...props} />} />
              <Route path="/d" element={<CompD {...props} />} />
            </Routes>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
```

The CompA, CompB, etc, are just different forms, nothing complicated. However any click on the side nav links renders the entire app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `Nav.Link` component renders a raw anchor tag by default. You want to render a `react-router-dom` `Link` component though.

Try importing the `Link` from `react-router-dom` and rendering that as the `Nav.Link` component.

See [Nav.Link props](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props).

Pass the `Link` to the `Nav.Link` component's `as` prop and change `href` to `to` for the `Link` component's target. You'll probably also want to use absolute paths.

Example:

```
import { Link, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<>
  <Navbar>
    <div></div>
  </Navbar>
  <Container fluid>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
        <Nav.Item href="/a">
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/a">Comp A</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/b">Comp B</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/c">Comp C</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/d">Comp D</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Col>
      <Col xs={8} sm={8} md={8} lg={9} xl={10}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/a" replace />} />
          <Route path="/a" element={<CompA {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/b" element={<CompB {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/c" element={<Compc {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/d" element={<CompD {...props} />} />
        </Routes>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
</>
```